# C# Visual Studio cannot import System.Data.OleDb library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, oledb

I'm new to C#/Visual Studio (coming from Python background) and am trying to connect to a database, but am failing to import the appropriate library. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and am creating a .NET Core application, and I have

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb; // this gets greyed out. "Using directive is unnecessary"

public class Program
{
    static OleDbConnection conn; //The type or namespace name 'OleDbConnection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference)
}
```

I can import System.Data without getting greyed out (although the OleDbConnection name still isn't found), but cannot figure out how to import System.Data.OleDb.

In solution explorer under the Project (ConsoleApp1), there are two items (Program.cs and Dependencies). I've tried right-clicking on dependencies --> Add Reference, but no options come up in the Projects, Shared Projects, or Browse folders.

What am I missing?

Comment: The type or namespace name 'OleDbConnection' could not be found (are you missing a directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: yes looks like you're right, this is a duplicate. thanks for sending the link